# How to program micro-controller after PCB is printed

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, circuit-design

noob here

So this may be a very dumb question but: after you program a micro-controller and get a PCB printed, how do you reprogram it if you want to change it? Also let's say you get a surface mount version of your initial prototype, how do you program that?

As I said, these may sound very silly, but I really don't know what's up with this PCB process

On another note, let's say I am prototyping with a HC-06 Bluetooth module and want to make the final version of my project much smaller, is there a SMD equivalent of this module?

Comment: that funtionality has to be included in the device design ... you have to design the circuit to allow `in-system programming`

Comment: Bring out whatever signals you need to program it to a connector, set of spring pin pads, edge connector, etc.  This has been asked and answered several times here before.  Questions should ask only one question; additionally your sourcing question on bluetooth modules looks like an off topic "shopping" question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The microcontroller manual will have a section that tells you which pins are associated with programming (usually some type of in-circuit serial programming interface (ICSP), typically a JTAG nowadays). You run these pins out to a connector on the board and you plug your computer into it through a piece of hardware called a programmer. It usually looks like a block with a USB cable on one end that goes to the computer, and a cable on the other end with a connector that plugs to your PCB. Then you use the programmer's associated software on the computer to upload code to your microcontroller.

Below is what I used for an STM32F303. It was to connect to a Segger J-Link USB programmer through a Tag-Connect TC2050 cable. Those 6 pins with net-names run straight to the MCU. The cable plugs into the PCB through 10-pins and plugs into the programmer through 20 pins (about half of which are just GND). I didn't use the programmer's original 20-pin ribbon cable to save PCB space.

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Some microcontrollers also have a bootloader pre-loaded onto them at the factory so that the microcontroller can program itself through signals received through one of it's regular interfaces (i.e. like UART or RS-232 from a PC). Of course, you can also write and upload your own bootloader to a microcontroller using the programmer. You might do this so that you do not need to use it in the future (so a customer can update their firmware in the field, for example), or allow other fancy programming behaviour. Bootloaders work by detecting searching for a specific signal sequence or jumpers on startup to know they are supposed to enter bootloader mode, otherwise they will execute their "normal" software.

Comment: Hmmm I see, does this significantly increase the complexity of a project? Particularly for a beginner @DKNguyen

Comment: @user19964 Not usually. The pins usually directly to the connector without any intervening hardware in between, except some lines may need pull-up resistors. It's one of the easier things to wire up on the board. Just look at your MCU manual and look at the pinout on your programmer and make sure to give it everything it wants. I would say that wiring up an LED circuit is more complicated. The difference is that if you mess up wiring an LED, your board isn't DOA. That alone makes it a bit nerve wracking the first time you do it, despite how simple it is.

Comment: @user19964 See attached images

Comment: Most of those signals aren't needed.  You really only need SWCLK, SWDIO, and to get out of certain stuck conditions, NRST.

Comment: @DKNguyen Thank you; that does actually help quite a bit...really appreciate it